# If matrix $A=[a_{ij}]_{4 \times 4}$ such that...

Tags: matrices, determinant, divisibility, fractional-part

> If matrix $A=[a_{ij}]_{4 \times 4}$ such that 
>   $a_{ij}=
> \begin{cases}
>  2&\text{if}\, i=j\\
>  0&\text{if}\, i \not= j\\
> \end{cases}$
>   , then
>   $\{\frac{det(adj(adjA))}{7}\}$ is ($\{x\}$ represent fractional part function)

Options

1. $\frac{1}{7}$
2. $\frac{2}{7}$
3. $\frac{3}{7}$
4. None

> Answer: $\frac{1}{7}$ (wolframalpha)

We know that determinant
$
|adjB|=|B|^{n-1}
$
where n is order of matrix. For this case replace $B$ by $adjA$ and n by 4, then the determinant

$
D=|adj(adjA)|=|adjA|^{3}=|A|^{9}
$

Also

$A=diag(2,2,2,2)$
hence
$|A|=2^4$

Therefore
$
D=2^{36}
$

Next we have to calculate fractional part of
$
\frac{D}{7}
$

that is
$
\{\frac{2^{36}}{7}\}
$

From looking onto the options

One way I can think of is subtracting a constant positive integer smaller than 7 from numerator and proving its divisibility by 7.

$
\frac{2^{36}-k+k}{7}=\frac{2^{36}-k}{7}+\frac{k}{7}
$

Then if we prove divisibility of $2^{36}-k$ by 7 then 
$
\frac{k}{7}
$
will be the answer.

But I cannot find a way to do that.

There might be alternative approach to get to final answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:
$$2^{36} = (2^3)^{12} = (1+7)^{12} = 1 + \sum_{i=1}^{12}\binom{12}{i}7^i = 1+ 7k,$$
where $k$ is an integer.